# Android fitting all buttons onto screen

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I have a row of buttons but there going outside of the width of the screen.  I tried making the buttons smaller but it not having a effect to it. Its a row of 11 circle buttons.  What can I do? Eventually I would like to make an grid of 11 by 11, any suggestions on how to do this better then one huge layout xml?

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                 <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_column="1" 
                    android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"/>
                  <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_column="1" 
                    android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"/>
                   <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_column="1" 
                    android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"/>
                    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_column="1" 
                    android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"/>
                     <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_column="1" 
                    android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"/>
                      <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_column="1" 
                    android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"/>
                       <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_column="1" 
                    android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"/>
                        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_column="1" 
                    android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"/>
                         <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_column="1" 
                    android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"/>
                          <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_column="1" 
                    android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"/>
                           <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
                    android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_column="1" 
                    android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"/>

        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

roundedbutton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#9F2200"/>
    <stroke android:width="2sp" android:color="#fff" />
        <size 
       android:width="5dp"
        android:height="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Added request to the answer

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;
    Log.d(TAG, "Position before convertView " + position );
    if (convertView == null) 
        {

            gridView = new View(context);

            // get layout from mobile.xml
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

            // set value into textview
            Button btn= (Button) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);

            if (position == 3)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Position inside convertView " + position );


                btn.setText("G"); 
                btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2E3135"));
                    //btn.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.goodguybutton);
            }
            else 
            {
                btn.setText(buttonTextValues[position]);
            }

        } 
    else 
        {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }




    return gridView;
}
```

Comment: you could create a custom view, `ButtonGrid`, extending FrameLayout, which instantiated the set of buttons in a set of nested for-loops.

Comment: This is interesting. Would I have access to each button if needed?

Comment: "Eventually I would like to make an grid of 11 by 11" ... so why you cant just create a gridView layout ? it will handle all fitting problems ... i had the same issue when i was developing crossword game ... i can write your a simple layout with custom adapter if you want to :)

Comment: You would be the man, if you could? Is your crossword source code available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gridView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</GridView>
```

item.xml

```
<Button 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="O"
android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
android:layout_column="1" 
android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"/>
```

custom button adapter class ... you can use it as inner class

```
public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private final String[] buttonTextValues;

    public ButtonAdapter(Context context, String[] buttonTextValues) {
        this.context = context;
        this.buttonTextValues = textViewValues;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

            // get layout from mobile.xml
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

            // set value into textview
            Button btn= (Button) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            btn.setText(buttonTextValues[position]);  
        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return buttonTextValues.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
```

}

activity:

```
public class ButtonGridView extends Activity {

        GridView gv;
        String[] buttonText = {"1", "2"}; //and so on to 11*11

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.gridView);
            gv =(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
            gv.setAdapter(new ButtonAdapter(this,buttonText));
        }
    }
```

also note that you can pass whatever information as you want to adapter with constructor and decide that button will have what color text or whatever you want ...

Comment: "this.buttonTextValues = textViewValues;" You have buttonTextValues being pass into the constructor but textViewValues are not resolving to anything at the moment? So if you were going to do something to each button, is the adapter where you would do it? For example I want the bottom left corner circle to be blue and right corner cirlce to be green, [Row,Col] [11,1] and [11,11]

Comment: sorry, there should be buttonTextValues insteadof textViewValues ... my bad ... also in your adapter you can call if the position == 11 || position == 110 and if its true then you canll btn.setColor(Color.BLUE); ...

Comment: So yes I can change text inside of getView but if I try to change color by pointing that position to a different roundbutton.xml with a different color, the result is a square of a total different color from either roundbutton.xml or roundbuttongreen.xml.  I'm not sure why?  I think maybe the settext works because I'm passing the text but I'm not passing a drawables so I'm not sure or color. Adding to code up top.

Comment: I figure it out...wrong command... btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttongreen);

Comment: How would you implement listener for each button?

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap all your buttons into a horizontaly aligned linear layout like this.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">    
    <Button 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1" 
      android:text="O"
      android:id="@+id/button1" 
      android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"/>
    <Button 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1" 
      android:text="O"
      android:id="@+id/button1" 
      android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I spotted that your question has actually two parts..You can just manually create the grid with two nested for loops..

Comment: A little confused on your suggestion. Each button should be wrapped in Linear Layout?  Or should I get rid of Table layout and Table row and wrap 11 inside of linear layout?